# Unity3D inaccurate location data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geolocation, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate distance for in an app I am prototyping in Unity. I have implemented several C# versions of the Harvestine equation I have found online and they all behave the exact same way...

```
public static float Haversine(float lat1, float lon1, float lat2, float lon2) {
    float R = 6372.8f; // In kilometers
    float dLat = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    float dLon = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = toRadians(lat2);

    float a = Mathf.Sin(dLat / 2) * Mathf.Sin(dLat / 2) + Mathf.Sin(dLon / 2) * Mathf.Sin(dLon / 2) * Mathf.Cos(lat1) * Mathf.Cos(lat2);
    float c = 2 * Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Sqrt(a));
    return R * 2 * Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Sqrt(a));
}

public static float toRadians(float angle) {
    return Mathf.PI * angle / 180f;
}
```

This is the Haversine C# function I am using...

But for some reason, without any variables changing, my total distance keeps increasing.
Note this function is called every 250ms, it's output then another var is used for testing to store a total distance travelled like this:

```
float Distance = Haversine (PreviousLocation.Latitude, RecentLocation.Latitude, PreviousLocation.Longitude, RecentLocation.Longitude);

TotalDistanceTravelled = TotalDistanceTravelled + Distance;
```

RecentLocation and PreviousLocation comes from a var storing location history, this data is the same as displayed in the video below

This is the output I get, note this is not the case in the editor, only in the build:

https://youtu.be/5B--WWJHOYE

Any help explaining this or suggesting some better code will be greatly appreciated! (I have a hunch it could have something to do with the radius?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are feeding the variables into the function (or using them) in the wrong order.

You currently have:

```
float Distance = Haversine (PreviousLocation.Latitude, RecentLocation.Latitude, PreviousLocation.Longitude, RecentLocation.Longitude);
```

According to how you are using the variables, however, I'm guessing you mean to do:

```
float Distance = Haversine (PreviousLocation.Latitude, PreviousLocation.Longitude, RecentLocation.Latitude, RecentLocation.Longitude);
```

Comment: Oh dear... I'll blame that on all the different variations of functions I pulled from the internet...

Comment: The distance calculation is still not great but definitely better with this latest function. Thanks for the help and sorry for the waste of time! haha

Comment: No worries. Takes a second set of eyes sometimes!